# Pages getting refreshed while switching between tabs

Tags: angularjs

I have a web page done in AngularJS. I got four tabs. In my first tab there are a set of images which I can select,

When i switch between tabs,and come back to the first page, the page gets refreshed and I loose what ever I have done in my 1st tab. Like tab gets refreshed like it was loaded again.In this 1st tab I got some drill downs ass well. That also gets reset.

How can I avoid this.

Comment: You can show some code on how you switch tabs. Is it the AngularJS UI tabs?

Comment: What are you using to create the tabs? If you're using ngRoute, it's supposed to work this way.